# Insert query in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am inserting fake records in table but it is not moving in database. You can check my code below :--

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',255)->unique();
            $table->string('contact_number');
            $table->timestamps();       
        });

        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        $limit = 33;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
            DB::table('employees')->insert([
                'name' => $faker->name,
                'email' => $faker->unique()->email,
                'contact_number' => $faker->phoneNumber,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong ? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the value to database you should use `seeder`. For seeder check here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding

Comment: public function run()
    {
         $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        $limit = 33;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
            DB::table('employees')->insert([
                'name' => $faker->name,
                'email' => $faker->unique()->email,
                'contact_number' => $faker->phoneNumber,
            ]);
        }
    }

Comment: Did you register your seeder in `DatabaseSeeder.php`?

Comment: Oh! Thanks. Its working now. I didn't register it in 'DatabaseSeeder.php' 

And one more thing, I ran the 'employee migration'. It creates the table in database but it is not included in the migration table in db. Is it normal ?

Comment: But what if I have to do this with migration file not with seeder ?

Comment: I mean what is the problem with my actual code ? Why should I need to make seeder ?

Answer (score 0):

Move this logic to the [seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding):

```
$limit = 33;

for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    DB::table('employees')->insert([
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->email,
        'contact_number' => $faker->phoneNumber,
    ]);
}
```

Then run `php artisan db:seed` command to execute seeders.

Answer (score 0):

Use **php artisan make:seeder EmployeesSeeder**, than write into your new seeder file this code:

```
class EmployeesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        Employee::truncate();

        foreach(range(1, 33) as $index)
        {
            Employee::create([
                'name' => $faker->name,
                'email' => $faker->unique()->email,
                'contact_number' => $faker->phoneNumber,
            ]);
        }                   
    }
}
```

More detailі [Database: Seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding)